# CosmosDb OrderBy first item in Array

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have about 2 million rows, the following cross partion query returns less rows than it should

```
select * from root r where r.isFile and  r.status = 0  order by r.addresses[0]
```

All items that match the WHERE filter do have an addresses[0] value, and many rows are returned without the order by statement. However with the order by statement, no rows are returned.

This query did work correctly as a single partition query. I suspect its a limitation with `order by` and cross partition queries, it's a adhoc query so performance is not a requirement.

Comment: What happens if you just do `order by r.addresses` ?

Comment: @NickChapsas I get rows, but some rows will have more than one address but need the order to be based on the `first` address not the addresses as a whole

Comment: @SteveDrake How does your sample document looks like? I tested on my side and it works though my items quite less than yours. I found order by did supports cross-partition queries from this doc:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/cross-partition-order-by-queries-now-available-in-documentdb-java-and-node-js-sdks/

Comment: Could it be that you are getting "partial results" and a continuation token?

Comment: I am paging and my paging code works fine when I omit the `order by`